# Another Grab Object in Django Query

Tags: python, django

I am again struggling with retrieving what I need from my database. This is still for a pretty basic library-style app in Django. I am still very new to Django - this is my first real full project. At any rate, in models, I set up the following Review table:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    star_rating = models.IntegerField()
    comments = models.TextField()

    book = models.ForeignKey("Book", 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="reviews")

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="reviews_added")
    created_at = 
        models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = 
        models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = ReviewManager()
```

Then in views, I have a route for books/home/ where I want to be able to display information for the current user (this part is done and works well) and also for that current user's reviews.

Here is my books_home method, currently. I believe I am close but I am not sure how to grab the Review objects. Unless I'm mistaken, I just need to replace the two instances of "???" below with real code. Your help is much appreciated.

```
def books_home(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        first_name = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).first_name
        last_name = 
User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).last_name
        email = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).email
        review_comments = Review.objects.get(id=???).comments
        review_rating = Review.objects.get(id=???).star_rating
        context = {
            'first_name' : first_name, 
            'email' : email,
            'last_name' : last_name,
            'review_comments' : review_comments,
            'review_rating' : review_rating
            }
        return render(request, 'html_files/home.html', context=context)
```

Apologies for the bad spacing here. It is correct in my actual files.

Current code:

```
def books_home(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
    first_name = 
    User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).first_name
    last_name = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).last_name
    email = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).email
    reviews = Review.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)
    context = {
        'first_name' : first_name, 
        'email' : email,
        'last_name' : last_name,
        'reviews' : reviews
        }
    return render(request, 'html_files/home.html', context=context)
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/gbroesche/Desktop/BeltReviewer/apps/book_reviewer/views.py" in books_home
  14.       reviews = Review.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  794.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  812.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1227.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1253.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1158.             self.check_related_objects(field, value, opts)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in check_related_objects
  1057.                 for v in value:

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  235.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: TypeError at /books/home/
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
```

YAY ME! With y'all's help, I was able to figure it out... I needed to define user_id as a variable then use it to filter all the reviews! I'm sure this is not as elegant as it could be, but the old motto: make it work, then make it work better. It works! Thanks everyone! Current code:

```
def books_home(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    first_name = 
User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).first_name
    last_name = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).last_name
    email = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).email
    user_id = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).id
    reviews = Review.objects.filter(created_by=user_id)
    context = {
        'first_name' : first_name, 
        'email' : email,
        'last_name' : last_name,
        'reviews' : reviews
        }
    return render(request, 'html_files/home.html', context=context)
```

Comment: So you want the `Review` comments and ratings from the user? Or from a certain `id`?

Comment: Do you want to get all the reviews or just the reviews which are given by the requested user?

Comment: I did not describe it well. I want to grab all reviews posted by the current user.

Answer (score 0):

to get the current logged on users details in a view you can just do

```
request.user
```

so your ??? will just be

```
request.user.id
```

Theres also no need to querying the users DB you can get this information directly in a template. in your template you can just do

```
First Name: {{ user.first_name }}
last Name: {{ user.last_name }}
Email: {{ user.email }}
```

Comment: Alexw, thank you. I can't get this to work, however. I understand that my code is a bit of a "long way around" but while I am trying to learn all the connections and references in a Django project I think that's OK. The real issue right now is grabbing the reviews. I tried this: `review_comments = Review.objects.get(id=request.user.id).comments` and I got a "matching query does not exist" error. Is there a way to leave most of my code intact but grab the Review objects?

Comment: using .get will not get you the users comments, you need to user .filter to get all the comments from that users

Comment: No, just trying to do it in views.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder regarding .get() and .filter(). You are totally right in this case, since there is not one specific comment. Nice catch. I still can't grab the Review objects thought!

Comment: can you update the question with how your code looks now?

Comment: def books_home(request):
 if request.method == "GET":
  first_name = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).first_name
  last_name = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).last_name
  email = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).email
  reviews = Review.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)
  context = {
   'first_name' : first_name, 
   'email' : email,
   'last_name' : last_name,
   'reviews' : reviews
   }
  return render(request, 'html_files/home.html', context=context)

Comment: Again, apologies for the spacing. I need to learn how to do that properly on StackOverflow!

Comment: See above - current code and traceback added to original question.

Comment: it looks like your user is not logged in currently

Comment: I am certain that current user is logged in. If I comment out anything having to do with the Review, the page loads properly with the user's information going correctly to the template. But then when I put the code pertaining to Review back, I again get the same error: AnonymousUser object not iterable.

Comment: comment out the code and then in your template put Logged on user: {{ user }} that will show you the logged on users name

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained your problem very clearly, but I think what you are asking is how to get all reviews added by the current user.

Firstly, you don't want to get comments and ratings separately; you want to get the Review objects, and then output the comments and ratings from there in the template. Secondly, to get a list rather than a single item you must use `filter`. And finally, you need to look up via the `created_by` field, rather than the id. So:

```
reviews = Review.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)
```

Then, in your template, you can iterate over reviews and show the comments and the ratings:

```
{% for review in reviews %}
    {{ review.comments }}
    {{ review.rating }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Daniel, yes you described my problem much more clearly than I did. This solution makes a lot of sense to me, thank you for pointing out that `.filter()` is the correct built-in function and that `created_by` is the field within the Review object that it makes sense to grab. However, now I am getting the error `'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`. I am certain that a user is currently logged in to the app.

Comment: Please show the updated code and the full traceback (as an edit to the question).